# Why am I getting a Seg Fault on this line of code in Qt creator/designer?

Tags: segmentation-fault, settext, qlineedit, qt4.8

I am using Qt4.8 RHEL6.5.

ui->le_config_0->setText("Today is Monday");
le_config_0 is a QLineEdit widget.

In the debugger this is the line it seg faults on.
I built the line typing ui-> and it gives a list and I chose the le_config_0 then -> and chose setText().

This doesn't make sense at all to me.

I tried changing the widget to a QTextEdit with the same results.  I'm wondering if my install of Qt has gotten corrupted or my QtCreator/Designer has gotten corrupted.

Thanks for any help
emp1953

Answer (score 0):

I created another simple GUI project with one QLineEdit widget and performed the same operation on it.
It worked perfectly.
Something in this project is corrupted.
I will start over with a new project.